# Undefined symbol in Catalogue of Spacetimes (Kerr metric)

Tags: general-relativity, notation, kerr-metric

In the [Catalogue of Spacetimes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4184), in the Kerr metric section, under "General local tetrad", there is a cluster of four equations (strangely labeled 2.14.6a and 2.14.6b!), two of which contain the symbol $\zeta$.  It also appears in 2.14.7.  As far as I can see that symbol is not defined anywhere, although it looks like it is probably some sort of angular quantity, being mostly associated with $\phi$.

Can anyone here shed some more specific light on what that symbol represents?

[EDIT]  If I were to *guess*, I would say it is a measure of "rotation" of the tetrad with respect to the "distant stars", so that a "non-rotating" tetrad would actually have to rotate "counter" to the black hole (in some sense) in order to remain pointing at a distant star ($\omega = - \zeta$).  Similarly a "static" tetrad would still need to rotate (by doing nothing, $\zeta = 0$, ?) to maintain its orientation with respect to the black hole.  All guess work though . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\zeta$ is just a parameter  that you can choose for yourself. It's a "general tetrad" after all. It looks like an angular velocity, but  in the next equations they spcify a "non-rotating" tetrad that still has an $\zeta=\omega$ angular velocity, but I assume that this is because  the frame dragging makes the notion of "non-rotating" ambiguous: are you non-rotating with respect to the distant stars, or to the event horizon.